# Relate kinetic energy to centripetal force of an object in fixed orbit rotation

Tags: energy

Am I correcting in equating using   energy = force * distance [$mv^{2}/2= (mv^{2}/r) r$]?

How is the kinetic energy only half the work done?

Answer (score 1):

Work is defined as force times displacement, but ONLY the component of the force that is parallel to the displacement contributes to work.  By definition, centripetal force occurs during circular motion, and it is always perpendicular to velocity, because velocity is always tangential to the circle while centripetal force always points towards the center of the circle, which means that centripetal force is always perpendicular to displacement.  Thus, the work done by a centripetal force is, by definition, zero.  This means that your assumption that kinetic energy equals centripetal force times displacement is incorrect.

Comment: Appreciate the explanation. Perhaps rewording my questions : for a rotating object in fixed orbit , whats the force that imparting energy to the rotating object , and how to relate the applied force to its kinetic energy ?

Comment: @eagleseye If the object in undergoing uniform circular motion, then the rotating object does not have any energy imparted to it. This is easily seen since its kinetic energy is not changing.

Comment: certipetal force gets the object onto circular motion . kinetic energy of that object in circular motion got its energy from velocity which in turn was from the centripetal force ?

Comment: Centripetal force does NOT get the object into circular motion.  A force that is tangent to the circle does that.  Also, kinetic energy does not arise from velocity, as dimensional analysis indicates that these two variables have different units.  Please take the time to read through a high school physics text book, covering the subjects of work, energy, and conservation of energy.

Comment: @eagleseye Some other force is needed to create the circular motion. For example, if you release a ball from rest above the earth, it is just going to fall. You would need to give the object sufficient energy and moving around the earth due circular motion to begin. The presence of a central force is not sufficient for circular motion.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, whats the equation to find that force sets an object on circular motion ? e.g. of a ball on string

Comment: @David "Also, kinetic energy does not arise from velocity"- how about v in mv^2 / 2  ?

Comment: @eagleseye, the answer is "no".  Kinetic energy arises from Newton's 2nd law, where acceleration is equal to F/m, and the work-energy theorem, where the change in kinetic energy is equal to the work done on the object.  That information can be found in any high school physics book, as I previously mentioned.

Comment: @David are you saying  mv^2 / 2 is not applicable in this scenario of fixed orbit rotating body  ?. And how would you calculate the work done or change in kinetic energy in this case ?

Comment: @eagleseye, your problem statement has to tell you that a given force was applied for a stated time interval in order to calculate change in momentum, and hence, velocity and kinetic energy.  And note: physics is NOT math.  Key concepts drive physics, and math is used to arrive at an equation or numeric answer after those concepts are recognized and used.  This means that mathematically, kinetic energy is a function of velocity, but normally, this fact is of little use when working circular motion physics problems.  Read a physics book for more info.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, the amount of work $dW$ done by a force $\vec F$ over some displacement $d\vec x$ is given by
$$dW=\vec F \cdot d\vec x$$

For a centripetal force, the force points in the $-\hat r$ direction (towards the center of the circle), and the infinetessimal displacement points in the $\hat \theta$ direction (tangent to the circle).

Therefore, for a given point in time in the rotation
$$dW=(-F\hat r)\cdot (\hat \theta dx)=0$$

Therefore centripetal forces don't do any work. The issue you have is common. $W=Fx$ is only true for constant forces along the direction of displacement. The other issue is that $r$ in your equations is a radius, not a displacement. You can't just multiply a force by a distance and say it is work or energy. Math in physics has physical meaning. You have to know what the equations mean and how to apply them correctly.